# AspectJ pointcuts and advice

Tags: aop, aspectj, pointcut

I have to enforce a policy issuing a warning if items not belonging to a particular category are being added, apart from the three which are allowed and disallowing such additions.....

So far i am able to find the items and issue warning.... but not sure how to stop them from being added....

For Eg.

Allowed categories Shoes and socks

but if i try and add a vegetable item to the inventory it should give me a warning saying "category not allowed../nItem will not be added to inventory"..... and then proceed to the next item....

This is what i've written so far.....

```java
pointcut deliverMessage() :
    call(* SC.addItem(..));

pointcut interestingCalls(String category) :
    call(Item.new(..)) && args(*, *, category);

before(String category): interestingCalls(category) { 
    if(category.equals("Socks")) {       
        System.out.println("category detect: " + category);
    else if(category.equals("Shoes"))
        System.out.println("category detect: " + category);
    else {
        check=true; 
        System.out.println("please check category " + category);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not use the `around` aspect instead. Then, if they are not of the correct category you don't go into that method, so it gets skipped, if the skipped method is just doing the adding.

**UPDATE:**

Here is an example from AspectJ In Action, by Manning Publication.

```
public aspect ProfilingAspect {
  pointcut publicOperation() : execution(public * *.*(..));
  Object around() : publicOperation() {
    long start = System.nanoTime();
    Object ret = proceed();
    long end = System.nanoTime();
    System.out.println(thisJoinPointStaticPart.getSignature()
      + " took " + (end-start) + " nanoseconds");
    return ret;
  }
}
```

So, if you wanted to check if you should add the item, if it is an allowed category then just call `proceed`, otherwise you would just return a null perhaps.